# JSONP $http request to Dreamfactory returns server error

Tags: angularjs, jsonp, angular-http

I am trying to access the dreamfactory data through $http request. To handle cross domain request, i have just added the JSON callback with the url.

```
.factory('DonorService', ['$resource','$http', '$q',
    function($resource,$http,$q){
    return{
        getDonors:function(){
            var donor = "https://dsp-sixerofsixes.cloud.dreamfactory.com/rest/db/icbd_donors/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&app_name=blooddonate&fields=*";
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.jsonp(donor).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}])
```

But on making the request it creates a internal server error in the df. while typing the url in the browser shows the data along with wrapping callback.

[Link to the JSON data](https://dsp-sixerofsixes.cloud.dreamfactory.com/rest/db/icbd_donors/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&app_name=blooddonate&fields=*)

[Link which is actually called from JSONP](https://dsp-sixerofsixes.cloud.dreamfactory.com/rest/db/icbd_donors/?callback=angular.callbacks._0&app_name=blooddonate&fields=*)

Comment: I see it properly too. Can you diagnose the internal server error?

Comment: Might also be a good idea to look at the request parameters sent using the network tab of the console(F12).

Comment: It seems to be an angular convention that JSONCALLBACK is converted to angular.callbacks._0. Thus making a request as [link](https://dsp-sixerofsixes.cloud.dreamfactory.com/rest/db/icbd_donors/?app_name=blooddonate&fields=*&callback=angular.callbacks._0) instead of the above one.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so I guess I'll have to write this here.

Remove the resource injection.  Just use $http.

ngResource incrementally creates those angular callback names.